# How can I detect a mouse click on a custom wx.Panel?

Tags: python-3.x, event-handling, wxpython, mouseevent

I am pretty new at both `Python` and `wxPython`. Anyway, after having followed the official tutorial where they explain how to do a basic text editor, I decided to go ahead and write a real text editor.

Now, my text editor consists of a `MainWindow` (which inherits from `wx.Frame`), which in turn contains a `Notebook` (inheriting from `wx.Notebook`) which in turn contains several *tabs* (a custom class inheriting from `wx.Panel`).

If I didn't misunderstand, events in `wxPython` can be detected and bounded to specific objects via the `Bind()` function.

Here's my custom panel class:

```
class TabContent(wx.Panel) :
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        # Calls the constructor for wx.Panel
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent, id = wx.ID_ANY)

        # Creates a vertical sizer
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Creates an empty multiline wx.TextCtrl
        textArea = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # Adds the text area to the sizer
        sizer.Add(textArea, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 2)

        # Sets the previously created sizer as this panel's sizer
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        # Sets up events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.onMouseLeftClicked)

    def onMouseLeftClicked(self, event) :
        print("Left button of the mouse was clicked\n")
```

[image: Editor]

I'd like to be able to detect right clicks on the tab itself (for example I could open a menu or just print something for the sake of testing wxPython functions). However, clicking with the mouse does not print anything. Any idea why?

By the way, I am on ArchLinux, using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3, Python 3.5.2 and wxpython 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

The event was actually being caught, but only on the very thin border of the tab.

Solved by putting the event handler in the `Notebook` class.